# Configuration for EF core to store multiple collection properties of the same type (value objects) in the single table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, discriminator, owned-types

Now I've realized that it is something hard to do for me.

Given:

**EF Core 8**

```cs
// мodels are simplified to highlight the essence

public class Notification
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public EmailAddress From { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<EmailAddress> To { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmailAddress> Cc { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmailAddress> Bcc { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAddress
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Need to get some configuration that the all email addressed will end up in the same table with some discriminator column maybe. Like

notification table

| id | from | subject | body |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

emailaddresses table

| id | notification_id | to | cc | bcc | discriminator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

or more preferable

| id | notification_id | address | discriminator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [table-per-hierarchy with a discriminator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration) feature to do this.

Extend `EmailAddress` to have a type per collection:

```
public class ToEmailAddress : EmailAddress { }
public class CcEmailAddress : EmailAddress { }
public class BccEmailAddress : EmailAddress { }
```

Modify `Notification` use the new types:

```
    public ICollection<ToEmailAddress> To { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CcEmailAddress > Cc { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BccEmailAddress> Bcc { get; set; }
```

Update the model configuration for `EmailAddress` to register the new types and desired discriminators:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<EmailAddress>()
        .HasDiscriminator<string>("discriminator")
        .HasValue<EmailAddress>("base")
        .HasValue<ToEmailAddress>("to")
        .HasValue<CcEmailAddress>("cc")
        .HasValue<BccEmailAddress>("bcc");
```

Comment: Hey @Matt Hensley, this is working approach, thanks. But as I've mentioned, `EmailAddress` is value object and have no identity (of course it can be tackled by adding shadow property), but the difficult for me is to achieve this result by configuring`EmailAddress`s as owned types. like notification ownsmany emailaddresses of different type (to, cc, bcc).